# How to convert 1433333912999732 to YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS using java

Tags: java, automation, google-bigquery

I am actually using Big Query to get the current db time, when run query select now(), it gives me output = 1433333912999732, now I need to use this somewhere else like  YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.
I am not sure if I can get the desired date YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS using the query it self.

Comment: The 1433333912999732 is the current time in millis. Just create a Date (java.util) object with it.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP();

Returns: 2013-02-01 01:33:35 UTC

check out more options
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#datetimefunctions

the value you get with now() is in microseconds
you can also try this

```
long unixSeconds = 1372339860;
Date date = new Date(unixSeconds*1000L); // *1000 is to convert seconds to      milliseconds
```

Comment: I tried this query, when I run this on google console it returns this 2013-02-01 01:33:35 UTC whereas when I run this query using java it returns this = 1.433335243673867E9

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 Date date = new Date(yourTimestamp.getTime());
 System.out.println(date);
```

then convert date to your format:

```
  DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
  String yourDate = df.format(date);
```

Comment: The format string is wrong. Note that the format string is case-sensitive. See the API docs of [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). Should be `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`